# how to properly append div at run time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello im trying to wrap a div with another div by using jquery append and im having one hell of a time.
  here is my div

```
<div id ="one" class="PortalBox" data-title="Concur">
    <div class = "localContent">
    FGDDDDDDDDDfdgdfffffffff
    dfgggggggggggggggggggggggggg
    dfggggggggggggggggggggggggg
    fgddddddddddddddddddddddddd
    fgddddddddddddd.
</div>

</div>
```

now what i would like to do is add an open div tag right above 
and then close it  after the closing tag related to local content. 
here is what i tried and i keep failing miserably.

```
   /*open div*/
    $('.localContent').each(function(idx, ele){
        //alert(ele.className);
        $('<div class="ab_Box1d" style ="width:630px">').insertBefore($(ele))
                })
    /*close the div*/   
    $('.localContent').each(function(idx, ele){
        //alert(ele.className);
        $('</div>').insertAfter($(ele))
                })
```

what is the proper way to do this? any help would be most appreciative.

Comment: So you want a result like `<div id="one"><div class="ab_Box1d"><div class="localContent">...</div></div></div>`?

Comment: yes exactly! Thats what im looking to do.

Comment: Then Joel's solution looks like what you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use jQuery's [wrap() function](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

```
$('.localContent').wrap('<div class="ab_Box1d" style="width:630px"/>');
```

Comment: Thank you Joel this defenetely works. one interesting note i noticed however is that the wrap function seem to now work correctly in certain conditions. I just had to reposition my divs so that it would work seems like a bug but i cant be entirely sure. thank you for responding.